# CakePHP 3 - postLink: document.post is undefined

Tags: javascript, cakephp, post, cakephp-3.0

I get the following error when using a postLink for deleting a record:

- document.post_573da0811d667564814578 is undefined

This looks like a Javascript error, but I did not add Javascript code myself.

This is my postLink (I use two parameters):

- `$this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), ['action' => 'delete', $p->id, $c], ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', $p->id)])`

This is my delete method:

```
public function delete($id = null, $c = null) {
    $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);

    // some code

    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index', $c]);
}
```

What could be the problem?

**Update**

- CakePHP version: 3.2.7
- The postLink is used inside a form.
- The generated html of the postLink:
- `<a onclick="if (confirm(&quot;Are you sure you want to delete #
  1836?&quot;)) { document.post_573da0811d667564814578.submit(); }
  event.returnValue = false; return false;" href="#">Delete</a>`

Comment: Please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly - thanks! Also please add some more context around your `postLink()` call (mostly important is whether it is being invoked inside of an open form), and show the generated HTML.

Comment: Added some extra info under 'Update'.

Comment: Didn't realise it became a form inside another form. Thanks for the reaction.